# about using "virtual ICollection..." in my model design?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4

I my asp.net mvc HR web apps, in my entity data model, in one page razor view, I have more than one model of data loaded and displayed, for example, in The Employee razor view, I want to display Employee data information on the top, but as the same I also want to display other ralated data with this employee such as Salary, Performance and Reveiw, all of these related data are seperated SQL table which is different EF model.

So to make it simple, one employee profile model has its ralated Salary, Performance and Review model (SQL table), so I use "virtual ICollection" in Employee Profile model.

```
 In Employee Profile model: I have these codes:
 public class EmpProfile
 {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Employee Name")]
    public string EmpName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Employee Number")]
    public string EmpNum { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Employee Title")]
    public string EmpTitle { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Department")]


    public virtual ICollection<PerfPlan> PerfPlans { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProgReview> ProgReviews { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProgEvaluation> ProgEvaluations { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<DevelopPlan> DevelopPlans { get; set; }
}
```

And in Employee Performance model, I have these codes (Salary and Review model are similar as this one):

```
 public class Performance
 {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int EmpProfileID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} is required.")]
    [Display(Name = "Name*:")]
    public string EmpName { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your Employee Number.")]
    [Display(Name = "Employee No.*:")]
    public string EmpNum { get; set; }
    ......
     public virtual EmpProfile EmpProfile { get; set; }
}
```

Now, after I build them, in my performance contoller, I found this line code in Create method:

ViewBag.EmpProfileID = new SelectList(db.EmpProfiles, "ID", "EmpName");

and in Create view generated by the controller, the EmpProfileID dropdownlist field is generated

@Html.DropDownList("EmpProfileID", String.Empty)

Can anybody tell me why the code ViewBag.EmpProfileID = new SelectList(db.EmpProfiles, "ID", "EmpName"); is generated in Create methed?

Answer (score 0):

Because all the generator knows or cares about is that `EmpProfileID` is a non-nullable int, so it creates a field to edit it. Since it's the id for a foreign key, it helpfully gives you a list of `EmpProfile` ids to choose from. If you don't want this field directly editable, you can remove it or change it to a hidden field. You just need to keep in mind that it will need to be set somehow, some way before you check `ModelState.IsValid` or you'll fail validation.

Comment: it makes scence, what if I changed public class EmpProfile
 {
    public int ID { get; set; }
 to public class EmpProfile
 {
    public int EmpProfileID { get; set; }
   do I still get that drowndownlist field in Performance? What really I want to do is to build the relation between EmployeeProfile and Performance, I do not want that dropdownlist generated.

Comment: I just tried as I mentioned above - I changed the Primary ID to EmpProfileID in Employee Profile model, but I still get ViewBag.EmpProfileID = new SelectList(db.EmpProfiles, "ID", "EmpName"); generated in my Performance controller, it seems I can not avoid it to be generated, I do not want user to edit this dropdownlist, I want to automatically set that field of data without user to edit and hide from the view. Any idea? it seems I can not remove it.

Comment: No. The generator is going to include every required field, explicit or not. But, just because it's generated doesn't mean you have to use it: just remove the field from the generated HTML if you don't want it there. If it really bothers you that much to have to modify the generated HTML, then just use a view model instead of your actual entity.

Comment: Just want to clarify it: The codes generated by MVC scalfolding has the codes of : ViewBag.EmpProfileID = new SelectList(db.EmpProfiles, "EmpProfileID", "EmpName"); in controller, and the codes of: <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("EmpProfileID", String.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmpProfileID)
        </div> in razor view, if I only kept the code in controller and remove the associated codes in razor view, then when I click "Create" to save the record, the data will not be saved as the dropdownlist field has been provided.

Comment: As I said in my answer, if you don't provide the field in the form, then you simply must ensure that the value is set somehow.

Comment: Thanks, I have found a way to set it up, it seems that if I use Icollection in model, the field of data is mandatory. thanks for your help